# Emacs equivilent jEdit's Code2HTML or VIm's :TOhtml?

Tags: emacs

How would one generate ***syntax-highlighted HTML output*** from an ***Emacs buffer***?
I'm interested in doing this for multiple languages (SQL, Python, etc.).

**jEdit** does this with the `Code2HTML` plugin described [here](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?Code2HTML)

**Vim** does this with the `:TOhtml` command with help file [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#%3aTOhtml) .

How would an Emacs user do this?

Also, I sometimes develop on Mac, Windows, and Linux, so I believe I would prefer to not depend on too many external commands/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [htmlize.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Htmlize) - it's "a package for exporting the contents of an Emacs buffer to HTML while respecting display properties such as colors, fonts, underlining, invisibility, etc."